# How do I Update a SQL Column with Random Numbers within a Range 1 - 10

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named 'project1everything' and a column in that table named 'views' and I need to updated that column to have a random set of numbers from 1 - 10, each row with a different number. I tried looking around but nothing is working. I am using I assume the newest version of MySQL :)

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing is working?" StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You are expected to make your best attempt to solve the problem. Please show us what you have tried, and let us know exactly what was wrong (error message, incorrect results, etc.).

Comment: *I need to updated that column to have a random set of numbers from 1 - 10, each row with a different number.* Do you mean that any random number must present in the final table state only once? What if the table contains more than 10 rows?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.